# Using a for loop

Tags: r

```
df1 <- data.frame(chrom = c("chr1","chr2", "chr5"), start=c(10,20,30), end = c(100,200,300), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(chrom = c("chr1", "chr4", "chr2"),start=c(15,500,150), end = c(75,1000,300), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

my answer should be:

```
chrom start  end
1  chr1    15   75

3  chr2   150  300
```

when I do the following:

```
for(i in 1:length(df2)){

for(j in 1:length(df1)){

if(df2$chrom[i] == df1$chrom[j])

    x <- df2[which(df1$chrom[j] == df2$chrom[i]),]

}
}
```

I get:

```
chrom start end
1  chr1    15  75
```

obviously my logic is wrong. Its only doing one iteration. Can someone help me understand? Maybe I am not made for this kinda stuff...anyways thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Thank you so much Vikram for editing....looks so much better!

Comment: Don't worry, everyone sucks at coding at first.  It gets better after 30 years or so, I'm told.

Comment: Now try changing `df1` so it has more rows.  What is `length(df1)`?  Then look at `nrow(df1)` and `ncol(df1)`.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what the for loop is for but maybe this is what you're after?

```
df2[df2$chrom %in% df1$chrom, ]
```

EDIT: to further poster's understanding:

```
> df2$chrom 
[1] "chr1" "chr4" "chr2"
> df2$chrom %in% df1$chrom
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> df1$chrom
[1] "chr1" "chr2" "chr5"
```

Comment: Hi Tyler,Thanks a ton again....it works well. Could you please explain what the %in% operator actually means?

Comment: yest the `x %in% y` is a binary operator that returns a logical TRUE FALSE value.  It basically says, "Does vector x match any items in vector y?"  Look at the edit I added.  "chr" in df2$chrom does match something in df1$chrom. "chr4 does not.  "chr2" or the last item in vector df2$chron does match an item in df1$chron.