# The for loop again

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(chrom=c("chr1","chr2","chr5"),
    start=c(10,20,30), end=c(100,200,300), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(chrom=c("chr1","chr4","chr2","chr1"),
    start=c(15,500,150,200), end=c(75,1000,300,300), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I want do the following:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
    # only if this condition is true (i.e. if there is overlap)
    if((df1$start <= df2$start && df1$end >= df2$start) ||
       (df1$start >= df2$start && df1$start <= df2$end)) {
        x <- df2[which(df2$chrom %in% df1$chrom),]
    }
}
```

The answer should be:

```
df3 <- data.frame(chrom=c("chr1", "chr2"), start=c(15,150),
    end=c(75,300), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Sorry for all the confusion.

People have been very patient with my queries and it has been a very helpful and learning experience. However I am trying to understand how looping works and the more I am thinking about it the more confused I am getting. For example:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
    x <- df2[which(df2$chrom %in% df1$chrom),]
}
```

does exactly the same as:

```
x <- df2[which(df2$chrom %in% df1$chrom),]
```

So you don't even need a loop. How is this possible? I guess `which` is doing the looping for you?

Comment: What's the QUESTION ? (I cannot see any question-mark except mine.)

Comment: Loops are loops, be it FORTRAN or Julia.  But you are right that the `[` operator can do very cool things.  May I recommend you read the R-inferno, http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf  ?

Comment: For your second question, look at your for loop. You *never* use the variable i. That means all you're doing is reassigning `x <- df2[which(df2$chrom %in% df1$chrom),]` again and again (so of course it does the same thing as just assigning it once)

Comment: I get it. I never use i so its not even recognizing the for loop. It simply evaluates x <- df2[which(df2$chrom %in% df1$chrom),]. But let's say I want to use the for loop to do the looping and get the desired result. How will I do it? Something like:                for(i in 1:length(df2)){

     if(df1$chrom == df2$chrom[i])
 x <- df2[where the above condition is true]

 }
}

Comment: We covered this base already in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083653/the-for-loop-aahh.  You didn't seem to take what you gained there and apply it here.  I don't understand how this question is any different than that; as Justin's response here is essentially the same as what I answered to what you asked before.  I believe this is a duplicate question hence the down vote.

Answer (score 2):

You can go even further:

```
df2[df2$chrom %in% df1$chrom,]
```

Since R is "vectorized" you're returning the rows from df2 that match the condition you've given.  Break it into its two parts:

```
> df2$chrom %in% df1$chrom  
[1] TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

That says that rows 1, 3 and 4 satisfy this condition.  Then we subset `df2` using that boolean vector.  R will only return rows that you've told it are `TRUE`.

```
> df2[c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE),]
  chrom start end
1  chr1    15  75
3  chr2   150 300
4  chr1   200 300
>
```

Is this helping?

EDIT per the comment:

The very un-R way would be nested for loops...

```
output <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
  foo <- NULL
  for(j in 1:nrow(df1)) {
    if(df1$chrom[j]==df2$chrom[i]) {
      foo <- df2[i,]
    }
  }
  output <- rbind(output, foo)
}
```

However, this is exactly what not to do in R...

Comment: Yes it is. I guess my queries have become more of (how loops work question) rather than a R question. I apologize for that. But what if I wanted to get the same answer without which() or %in%. Just using a for loop and the i. How would I accomplish that? I know R is not meant to be used in this way but just curious?

Comment: Hi Justin,sorry for the late reply....but you saved the day. Thanks you so much. I know it not the happy way of doing it but I just wanted to know how it would work. Thank you so much!